# Remove access to CNAME of application and allow access only to rerouted domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I have an application running on Elastic Beanstalk, which I can access using its CNAME: `http://NameOfApp.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/`.

Using `Route 53` I created an alias on a domain I bought and rerouted the traffic to it. I have also added an SSL and therefore can access the app on `https://FooBar.com`.

But while doing so, I thought app will not be available on its CNAME anymore, which is not the case. I want the app to be accessible only on the domain `FooBar.com`. Any help with arranging it like so would be great.

Comment: Are you using load balancing?

Comment: @mokugo-devops yes I do

Comment: If you're using an ALB you have a few options. Either configure a redirect rule when the Host header is anything but that DNS name, or attach a WAF and block all requests other than the host header

Comment: First option seems good, would you have any links/articles? I am very new to this and have hard time even googling what I need.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-advanced-request-routing-for-aws-application-load-balancers/. This should add scope. BAsically add a rule to listener for if host name is `NameOfApp.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com` then do a redirect to `https://FooBar.com`